# Relation between solutions of two sums

Tags: summation, proof-writing

I would like to show that the solutions $x$ to the following equation
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N {A_n \over x-r_n} = 0
$$
are $\textit{not}$ also solutions to the equation
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N {A_n \over (x-r_n)^2} = 0
$$
for $A_n$ satisfying $\sum_{n=1}^N A_n =0$ (the $A_n$ are not all zero, and $N\geq 3$). Is this true in general? My approach for trying to solve this has been to assume that there $\textit{is}$ such a solution $x$ and try to obtain a contradiction. For example, if there were such an $x$, then we would have 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N {A_n \over (x-r_n)^2} = 0 = \sum_{n=1}^N {A_n \over x-r_n}
$$ 
$$\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^N {A_n \over x-r_n} \left({1+r_n - x \over x-r_n}  \right) = 0
$$
but I'm not really sure where to go from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$
\sum_{n=1}^N {A_n \over x-r_n}  = \sum_{n=1}^N {A_n \over (x-r_n)^2} (x - r_n) = x \sum_{n=1}^N {A_n \over (x-r_n)^2} + \sum_{n=1}^N {A_n r_n \over (x-r_n)^2} 
$$
 If x solves both equations, then the first term is zero, and we have 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N {A_n r_n \over (x-r_n)^2} =0
$$
However, this is a different equation from 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N {A_n \over (x-r_n)^2} =0
$$
unless we have special cases that the coefficients $A_n$ and $A_n r_n$ are all proportional to each other.

So other then in these cases, the two equations have exactly the same structure, but with different coefficients, so  they won't have the same solution. This establishes the contradiction.

Comment: Great, thank you for this clear and concise answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is false in general.

**Counterexample:**

Take $$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-1)} + \frac{1}{(x-2)}+\frac{1}{(x-3)}= 0$$

Notice that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+}f(x)=\infty$. By Intermediate Value Theorem, we get that a root lies between $1$ and $2$.

Similarly, a root lies between $2$ and $3$.

Note that when $x<1$, we get no real root as

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-1)} + \frac{1}{(x-2)}+\frac{1}{(x-3)} < 0 $$

Similarly, when $x>3$, we get no real root.

But on the other hand,

$$g(x)=\frac{1}{(x-1)^2} + \frac{1}{(x-2)^2}+\frac{1}{(x-3)^2} > 0$$

So, it has no real roots.

Comment: This is a nice, explicit example - thanks Roby5!

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
f(x) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {{{A_{\,n} } \over {\left( {x - r_{\,n} } \right)}}} \quad  \Rightarrow \quad {d \over {dx}}f(x) =  - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {{{A_{\,n} } \over {\left( {x - r_{\,n} } \right)^{\,2} }}} 
$$
then $x_s$ will be a solution of both only if it is a zero with multiplicity $\geq 2$
of the resulting rational function.